# TicTacToeAI with Minimax Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax

I have implemented Minimax Algorithm for Tic Tac Toe Game from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-3-tic-tac-toe-ai-finding-optimal-move/?ref=rp). I know how the Minimax Algorithm works but my code here doesn't work according to it. I have checked and checked for the things I might be doing wrong and also have debugged it. But it seems, I am not able to find it.

Please look into the algorithm, it would be much thankful for extra set of eyes and to find the incorrect part which I can't seem to find.

I have commented every part of the code that is helpful with Minimax Algorithm. I think it would be easy to catch up.

Please help me out here.

Thank you.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Move {
    // row index
    protected int row;
    // column index
    protected int col;
    // exp is 'Our Expression'.
    protected char exp;
    // oppExp is 'Opponent's Expression'
    protected char oppExp;
}

class TicTacToe {

    private final char[][] arr = new char[3][3];

    // Move - to keep track of rowIndex and columnIndex
    // from the minimax algorithm. And to keep track of
    // 'X'/'O', who is our opponent for which the algorithm
    // should find moves for. 
    private final Move moves = new Move();

    TicTacToe() {
        // Initialising field
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Arrays.fill(this.arr[i], ' ');
        }
    }

    public String[] whosePlaying(Scanner sc) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Input command: ");
            // Getting input for players vs players
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            if (str.startsWith("start")) {
                String[] players = str.replaceAll("start", "").trim().split(" ");
                if (players.length == 2) {
                    if ((players[0].equals("user") || players[0].equals("ai")) &&
                            (players[1].equals("user") || players[1].equals("ai"))) {
                        return players;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Bad parameters!");
        }
    }
    
    public void playUser (Scanner sc, char exp) {   // exp is expression('X' / 'O') for user

        // x is RowIndex
        // y is ColumnIndex
        // To get from the user
        int x, y;
        System.out.print("Enter the coordinates (According to Matrix, Space separated integers): ");

        while (true) {

            // try - catch for input that might not be number
            try {
                sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                x = sc.nextInt();
                y = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");

                playUser(sc, exp);  // Ask again for coordinates
            }
        }

        if (x > 2 || y > 2 || x < 0 || y < 0) {
            System.out.println("Coordinates should be from 0 to 2!");

            playUser(sc, exp);  // Ask again for coordinates
        } else {
            // Check for availability.
            if (this.arr[x][y] == ' ') {
                this.arr[x][y] = exp;
                displayField(); // Displaying TicTacToe field after user's turn.
            } else {
                System.out.println("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!");

                playUser(sc, exp);  // Ask again for coordinates
            }
        }
    }

    public void playComputer (char exp) {
        System.out.println("Making move level \"AI\"");

        // Setting our expresssion that is X / O.
        moves.exp = exp;
        // Finding opponents expresssion that is X / O.
        if (moves.exp == 'X') moves.oppExp = 'O';
        else moves.oppExp = 'X';

        // Searching for the best move.
        searchBestMove();

        // Setting the best coordinates from the minimax algorithm
        // into the field with our expresssion.
        this.arr[moves.row][moves.col] = moves.exp;
        displayField(); // Displaying TicTacToe field after AI's turn.
    }
    
    // Start of Minimax Algorithm -  Contains all methods needed for the algorithm
    private void searchBestMove() {
        int bestVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        moves.row = -1;
        moves.col = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (this.arr[i][j] == ' ') {
                    this.arr[i][j] = moves.exp;
                    int moveVal = minimax(0, false);
                    this.arr[i][j] = ' ';

                    if (moveVal > bestVal) {
                        moves.row = i;
                        moves.col = j;
                        bestVal = moveVal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int minimax(int depth, boolean isMax) {
        int score = checkGetScore();

        if (score == 10 || score == -10) return score;
        if (!checkForSpace()) return 0;

        int best;
        if (isMax) {
            best = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (this.arr[i][j] == ' ') {
                        this.arr[i][j] = moves.exp;
                        best = Math.max(best, minimax(depth + 1, false));
                        this.arr[i][j] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            best = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (this.arr[i][j] == ' ') {
                        this.arr[i][j] = moves.oppExp;
                        best = Math.min(best, minimax(depth + 1, true));
                        this.arr[i][j] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }

    // Check for the score if the AI wins in the upcoming move
    // This method helps AI to assign score for each way in the game while searching.
    private int checkGetScore() {
        // For Rows
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (this.arr[i][0] == moves.exp && this.arr[i][1] == moves.exp && this.arr[i][2] == moves.exp) {
                return 10;
            } else if (this.arr[i][0] == moves.oppExp && this.arr[i][1] == moves.oppExp && this.arr[i][2] == moves.oppExp) {
                return -10;
            }
        }
        // For Cols
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (this.arr[0][i] == moves.exp && this.arr[1][i] == moves.exp && this.arr[2][i] == moves.exp) {
                return 10;
            } else if (this.arr[0][i] == moves.oppExp && this.arr[1][i] == moves.oppExp && this.arr[2][i] == moves.oppExp) {
                return -10;
            }
        }
        // For Diagonals
        if (this.arr[0][0] == moves.exp && this.arr[1][1] == moves.exp && this.arr[2][2] == moves.exp) {
            return 10;
        } else if (this.arr[0][0] == moves.oppExp && this.arr[1][1] == moves.oppExp && this.arr[2][2] == moves.oppExp) {
            return -10;
        } else if (this.arr[0][2] == moves.exp && this.arr[1][1] == moves.exp && this.arr[2][0] == moves.exp) {
            return 10;
        } else if (this.arr[0][2] == moves.oppExp && this.arr[1][1] == moves.oppExp && this.arr[2][0] == moves.oppExp) {
            return -10;
        }

        return 0;
    }
    // End of Minimax Algoritm

    // Displays results of Win / Tie by checking Rows, Columns and Diagonals.
    public boolean displayResult() {
        int valR = checkRows();
        int valC = checkCols();
        int diag = checkDiag();
        if (diag == 1 || diag == 3 || valR == 3 || valC == 3) {
            System.out.println("X wins");
            return true;
        } else if (diag ==  2 || diag == 4 || valR == 2 || valC == 2) {
            System.out.println("O wins");
            return true;
        } else if ((diag == 0 || valC == 1 || valR == 1) && checkForSpace()) {
            System.out.println("Draw");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Prints the TicTacToe field
    public void displayField () {
        System.out.println("---------");
        for (char[] a : this.arr) {
            System.out.print("| ");
            for (char b : a) {
                System.out.print(b + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.println("---------");
    }
    
    // Checks for the availability of space
    // in the TicTacToe field.
    private boolean checkForSpace() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (this.arr[i][j] == ' ') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Checks the Diagonals of the field
    private int checkDiag() {
        if (this.arr[0][0] == 'X' && this.arr[1][1] == 'X' && this.arr[2][2] == 'X') {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.arr[0][0] == 'O' && this.arr[1][1] == 'O' && this.arr[2][2] == 'O') {
            return 2;
        } else if (this.arr[0][2] == 'X' && this.arr[1][1] == 'X' && this.arr[2][0] == 'X') {
            return 3;
        } else if (this.arr[0][2] == 'O' && this.arr[1][1] == 'O' && this.arr[2][0] == 'O') {
            return 4;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Checks the Rows of the field
    private int checkRows () {
        int cntX = 0,
                cntO = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (this.arr[i][0] == 'X' && this.arr[i][1] == 'X' && this.arr[i][2] == 'X') {
                cntX++;
            } else if (this.arr[i][0] == 'O' && this.arr[i][1] == 'O' && this.arr[i][2] == 'O') {
                cntO++;
            }
        }

        if (cntX == 1) {
            return 3;
        } else if (cntO == 1) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Checks the Columns of the field
    private int checkCols () {
        int cntX = 0,
                cntO = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (this.arr[0][i] == 'X' && this.arr[1][i] == 'X' && this.arr[2][i] == 'X') {
                cntX++;
            } else if (this.arr[0][i] == 'O' && this.arr[1][i] == 'O' && this.arr[2][i] == 'O') {
                cntO++;
            }
        }

        if (cntX == 1) {
            return 3;
        } else if (cntO == 1) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}

public class MinimaxAlgorithm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        TicTacToe tic = new TicTacToe();

        // For game to start specify players
        // Eg: start user ai    <-- user is X and user chance comes first.
        // Eg: start ai user    <-- ai is X and ai chance comes first.
        // Eg: start ai ai      <-- ai vs ai
        // Eg: user user        <-- user vs user
        String[] players = tic.whosePlaying(sc);

        // Displays the empty field of TicTacToe
        tic.displayField();

        // turnX = true. X's turn
        // turnX = false. O's turn
        boolean turnX = true;

        while (true) {

            // Alternate player turns
            // First chance of X, than O.
            if (turnX) {
                switch (players[0]) {
                    case "ai":
                        tic.playComputer('X');
                        break;
                    default:
                        tic.playUser(sc, 'X');
                        break;
                }
                turnX = false;
            } else {
                switch (players[1]) {
                    case "ai":
                        tic.playComputer('O');
                        break;
                    default:
                        tic.playUser(sc, 'O');
                        break;
                }
                turnX = true;
            }

            // displayresult() - Checks if the game is over by anyone winning or tie.
            // If someone wins or ties the "check" becomes true and finishes the game.
            // Checks after each move made by the players.
            boolean check = tic.displayResult();
            if (check) break;
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

The blue arrow indicates where the mistake happened.
The green marking specifies how it should have been.
[image: Working]

CONSOLE:

```
Input command: start user ai
---------
|       |
|       |
|       |
---------
Enter the coordinates (According to Matrix, Space separated integers): 1 1
---------
|       |
|   X   |
|       |
---------
Making move level "AI"
---------
| O     |
|   X   |
|       |
---------
Enter the coordinates (According to Matrix, Space separated integers): 0 2
---------
| O   X |
|   X   |
|       |
---------
Making move level "AI"
---------
| O O X |    <-- Explanation: The AI made its move on [0, 1] 
|   X   |                    but it should have did on [2, 0]
|       |                    which will block my win on right diagonal.
---------
Enter the coordinates (According to Matrix, Space separated integers): 2 0
---------
| O O X |
|   X   |
| X     |
---------
X wins
```

Comment: I think "doesn't work" is a little too vague. How doesn't it work? What is it suppose to do instead? You have "debugged it" how? What have you eliminated? Right now, you've pasted in 354 lines of code & comments and sort of said "Find/fix the error"

Comment: Yes. I am sorry for such vague question. I will edit the question.

Comment: I think you'll need to add input/output and actual versus expected results.

Comment: @Scratte Is it better now? What other information can I provide?

Comment: Not everyone can access images. I think there should probably be text as well. But.. 0 2 seems to be 0 "row" and 2 "column", making it the upper right corner. So I'm not sure why you say this is not working. Unless you really mean to say "The AI should have placed the 'O' at 2 0, but instead it placed it at 0 1".

Comment: Yes. I will add text too. Yes [0, 2] was my move after which AI made its move which should be where the green mark is present but it did his move on [0, 1] , it should have blocked my two X's on the diagonal but it didn't.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat . Actually I read somewhere that if we can't decide what modifier to use, we should use the most strict one for now and if need be later we should change the modifier.

Comment: `protected` is normally only used in the context of (planned) inheritance. So I would rather drop it, and have no modifier (so: "package protected visibility") . Also note: your default policy should be to make all fields final. That is much more important. The less ways there are to introduce side effects, the better. And the ability to just reset some fields of some objects to other values can cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: Unrelated, but the depth parameter is not use in the function minimax(). You might want to return score - depth (or score + depth in the minimizing (-10) case), so your AI try to win as fast as possible and not just to win.

Comment: @mrBen Thank you so much. Yes it will be much better. So just to make sure I have to make changes in the minimizing case and put score + depth in it, right?

Comment: Serum, yes, in your case the score should not change sign, so with a max depth of 9 (9 possible position in tic tac toe) from +10 to +1 for the maximizer and from -10 to -1 for the minimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a mismatch between your function `checkForSpace()` and its use in `minimax()`. If there is space left you return `false` and if you get a `false` in `minimax()` you stop the search as if there is a tie. You need to invert the boolean in `checkForSpace()` or remove the logical not in `minimax()`.

You should propably rename `checkForSpace()` and other function that return a boolean. From *The Art of Readable Code* (Dustin Boswell and Trevor Foucher):

> When picking a name for a boolean variable or a function that returns a boolean, be sure it’s clear what `true` and `false` really mean.
>
> Here’s a dangerous example:
>
> ```
> bool read_password = true;
> ```
>
> Depending on how you read it (no pun intended), there are two very different interpretations:
>
> - We *need* to read the password
> - The password has already *been* read
>
> In this case, it’s best to avoid the word "read," and name it `need_password` or `user_is_authenticated` instead.
>
> In general, adding words like `is`, `has`, `can`, or `should` can make booleans more clear.
>
> For example, a function named `SpaceLeft()` sounds like it might return a number. If it were meant to return a boolean, a better name would be `HasSpaceLeft()`.
>
> Finally, it’s best to avoid *negated* terms in a name. For example, instead of:
>
> ```
> bool disable_ssl = false;
> ```
>
> it would be easier to read (and more compact) to say:
>
> ```
> bool use_ssl = true;
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much @mrBen . Damn the mistake I did.

Comment: The one thing to add here: your code example are not following java naming conventions. Java uses camelCase, so it is `useSsl`, not `use_ssl`.

Comment: Well, that a good exemple of why proper naming is important!

Comment: GhostCat for some reason I was sure Serum code was C#... Anyway that's a good point, I just copy paste content from the book, but one should follow the coding style of the language or the project he's working on.